# Testing constraints on has_many with rspec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm using [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) with rspec to test `has_many` relationships on my Rails models. eg:

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
  has_many :other_children, :through => :intermediate
end

# spec/models/parent_spec.rb
describe Parent do
  it "has children" do
    should have_many(:children)
    should have_many(:other_children).through(:intermediate)
  end
end
```

That's all working fine. But how do I best test extra constraints on these relationships, such as when there is:

```
has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :children, :uniq => true
has_many :children, :through => :intermediate, :source => :partner
```

Comment: `Shoulda-matchers` now [have](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#have_many) `dependent` and `through` matchers. I didn't saw `uniq`, but you can easily look at source code and perform what you want in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for same and found that [there are](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveRecord#have_many-instance_method) defined matchers for different Qualifiers, including :dependent, :through and :source, but for :uniq, I didn't find...
Maybe because of it's deprecated it in Rails 4...